# Solr DIH dynamic filed name & convert value

Tags: lucene, solr, dih

I have a working solr with DIH now i need to add multi rows which is ONE to MANY relationship with the solr indexed doc

```
TABLE:
ID:int PK
post_id:int FK
name:string
value:text
type:(int|string)
```

i need to insert all rows based on FK (post_id) into solr doc with dynamic name and convert value based on type

```
SELECT name,value,type FROM TABLE WHERE post_id='${post_entity.id}';

loop
insert into solr fieldname: meta_{$name} value: if type int cast to int else just value
end loop
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have the answer yet, but my understanding is you need to create multiple entity tabs in the data handler document, one for each new multi-value field you want to add, and indicate the ID from the root document. Look at this example:
In the DataHandler.xml file:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource name="jdbc" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/bedrock" user="postgres" password="test" batchSize="1000" readOnly="true" autoCommit="false" transactionIsolation="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" holdability="CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT" />
<document name="doc-a">
    <entity name="employee-root" datasource="jdbc" pk="id" query ="
        select
            a.id as id,
            a.name as name,
            a.dept as dept,
            a.jobtitle as jobtitle,
            a.last_change as last_change
        from employee a
        "
    transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer,TemplateTransformer">
        <field column = "id" />
        <field column = "name" />
        <field column = "dept" />
        <field column = "jobtitle" />
    <entity name="employee-hobby" datasource="jdbc" query ="
        select
            employee_hobby as features
            from employee_hobby 
            where employee_id = ${employee-root.id}
        "
        transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer,TemplateTransformer">
        <field column = "features" />

    </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Comment: thanks adolfo, indeed i created multi entities inside my DIH config but what i need here is doing extra process inside the sub entity process

Answer (score 0):

i think i can use DIHCustomTransformer to invoke a function but i am not sure yet
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHCustomTransformer

any enlightenment will be appreciated